# opencv video read libpng error

Tags: opencv, libpng

I am having the the following error! while capturing video.

```
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR 
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR 
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
```

video capture code is perfectly running on Ubuntu (Linux 3.8.0-29-generic ) but having error while running in Redhat (Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64). For redhat I checked with image read-write, which is working fine. In short, I can read-write images but can not work with video.

Comment: PNG isn't a video format.

Comment: The point is, video file can not be opened. Gave error messages so that people with similar problem who had the solution can give me suggestion.

Comment: Well, my suggestion is to not try to open the video file with libpng, which seems to be what you are doing.  I'm surprised that you did not get "Not a PNG file" as the error message, though.  You'd need to prepend the PNG 8-byte signature, or ignore it somehow, to fall through to the IHDR chunk checking.